# file handle error

Tags: perl

I'm trying to open a device list file to run a command but getting an "unopened filehandle" error. How I can fix that? The error is on the `while (<List>) {` line.

```
#!\usr\bin\Perl\bin\perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use NET::SSH2;
use MIME::Base64;
my $host = "C:/temp/devices.txt"; # input file
my $user = "XXX"; # your account
my $pass = "XXXXX"; # your password  64 bit mime
my $ssh2 = Net::SSH2->new();
my $result = "C:/temp/result1.txt"; # output file
$ssh2->debug(1); # debug on/off
open(List, '<', "$host" ) or die "$!";
           my @lines = <List>;
           for my $line (@lines) {
    $ssh2->connect($line) or die "Unable to connect host $@ \n";
    my $dp=decode_base64("$pass");
    $ssh2->auth_password("$user","$dp");
    my $chan = $ssh2->channel();
    $chan->exec('sh ver');
    my $buflen =30000;
    my $buf1 = '0' x $buflen;
    $chan->read($buf1, $buflen);
    close (LIST);
    #### ## print in file
    open (OUTPUT, '>', "C:/temp/result.txt") or die "$!";
    open (OUTPUT, '>', "$result") or die "$!";
    print OUTPUT "Result For:", "$host\n", $buf1,"\n";
    close (OUTPUT);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `List` is lowercase in the while loop, and upper case `LIST` in the rest. Perl is case sensitive.

To the rest of the code, it's not obvious what you're trying to do. Assuming you need to do something line-by-line from the LIST, then replace your while loop with:

```
for my $line (@lines) {
```

then in your code, whereever you need the "current line", use `$line`.

I can't comment on the usage of the ssh module here; haven't used it myself.

Comment: thanks..stupid me! now is is no error but no out put just blank even with debug on..appears to be the file been read but the command not passed.

Comment: You have two opens right after each other, be sure you are looking in the right place for the result.

Comment: thanks, my new error is "Unable to connect host IO::Socket::INET: Bad hostname 'C:/temp/devices.txt'"

Comment: That's because you are actually connecting to the file as to a server, on the line `$ssh2->connect($host)`.

Comment: And I am not sure you're doing what you think you're doing with the `while` cycle - it repeats what you have in the curly brackets for every line of the file, while it saves the contents of the line to `$_` variable.

Comment: you are correct thanks for that. I have changed to ` open(List, '<', "$host" ) or die "$!";my @lines = <List>;for my $line (@lines) { $ssh2->connect($line) or die "Unable to connect host $@ \n";`  now I am able connect but only on one device on the list. not going to the other list.